# Should I use original version subtitles or subtitles in my language?

Tags: self-learning, subtitles

I watch every TV series and movies in English but sometimes I can't understand some really specific words that are rarely used by the English native speakers themselves.

Should I use subtitles in my native language so that I can at least learn the meaning of the word? Or should I use English subtitles and take the time to look the word up on the Internet?

Thanks!

Comment: I think which you should do depends on your learning goal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it would be more beneficial to have English subtitles.  It would help you link the sound of a word to how it is spelled.  If you don't know a word - pause the show and look it up. Given today's' technology, it is relatively quickly.

Having subtitles in a different language will most likely confuse you more than help you, because you have to hear one language, but read another one. 
This is given that you have at least a basic proficiency in English, but based on the quality of the question - I think you do :)

This thinking on mine is based on an idea that you should immerse yourself in a language as much as you can in order to start "natively" thinking and speaking in it.